# Loading images disaligns document

Tags: graphics, horizontal-alignment, grouping

I do not know whether the question has already been asked,

Since I'm a rookie writing in latex, I'd like to know what I'm missing when i upload an image on my document, because it disaligns completely all the text,

The image is uploaded with the following :

```
\centering\includegraphics[width=0.3\textwidth]{Nameoftheimage}
```

I'm gonna link two pictures to make myself more clear.

The package used are :

```
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{commath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{pgfplots,tikz}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.5}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{4}
\usepackage[left=1.3in]{geometry}
```

before

[image: Before]

after

[image: After]

Comment: unrelated comments on your package list, you don't need `amsmath` if you load `mathtools`, `hyperref` should usually be loaded last,  don't use `blindtext` in a real document, I would rather strongly suggest not using `commath`

Comment: Why? Are there influences between each other?

Comment: `mathtools` loads `amsmath`, so no need to specify it, `hyperref` has to change lots of things to enable linking so is best loaded last, `blindtext` is just for generating nosense text examples,  and `commath` is what it is...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
\centering\includegraphics{..}
```

applies `\centering` to the rest of the document, use

```
\begin{center}
\includegraphics{...}
\end{center}
```

Comment: Do be aware that this adds vertical space above and below the inserted graphic.  If you want to avoid this space, an alternative formulation is `\begingroup \centering ... \endgroup`.

Comment: @barbarabeeton with a `\par` or blank line before the endgroup, yes I decided not to mention that possibility, a non-floating image normally benefits from the vertical offset in anycase

Comment: Of course, you're correct about the `\par`.  If the following text doesn't start a new paragraph, it would even be possible to treat it as an unnumbered equation -- `\[ ... \]` -- which would get some extra space above and below, though usually not as much as added by `center`.